# New to R, "unexpected symbol error" caused by typo

Tags: r, legend

I am trying to write a table legend in R using this line of code:

```
legend("bottomright", inset=c(0,-0.7), c("valley", "ridge"),  pch=c(2,17) col=c("red", "blue"), bty="n", xpd=TRUE)
```

I keep receiving this error code:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "legend("bottomright", inset=c(0,-0.7), c("valley", "ridge"),  pch=c(2,17) col"
```

I have tried fixing my line of code, but at this point I am not sure what the problem is. Any and all help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: do you mean to have a comma before 'col'?

Answer (score 2):

you are missing a comma after `pch=c(2,17),`